# HTML5 Web Notification - Genexus

Tags: genexus

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em Genexus Ev3 com gerador em .NET. Preciso criar uma notificação no desktop, através do navegador. Encontrei o User Control "Web Notification" que utiliza HTML5, porém, não consegui fazer com que ele funcione. Alguém tem algum exemplo de como esse user control funciona ou outra forma de realizar isso no genexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converti a KBase para Genexus 15 e o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Você pode usar o próprio recurso do GeneXus, sem necessidade de User Control:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikiprinterfriendly?33633,37

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikiprinterfriendly?22527,39

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar dessa forma. Já testei o User Control no Genexus 15. Lá funcionou. Em uma instância vou precisar converter.